# Angular : show value without update

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs

I want to show value of variable with initial status. I dont want to show update when value is changed

```
<span>{{value}}</span>
```

Something like this, but without updating this span when value is changed

Comment: Just don’t change that value.   If set in your constructor, create a second variable for this and don’t change it

Answer (score 1):

.ts:

```
valueThatWontChange: any

ngOnInit() {
  this.valueThatWontChange = this.value
}
```

.html:

```
{{ this.valueThatWontChange }}
```